# What is the fastest way to filter over 2.5gb Json file?

Tags: python, json

I have 2.5 GB of JSON file with  25 columns and about 4 million rows. I try to filter the JSON with the following script it takes at least 10 minutes.

```
import json

product_list = ['Horse','Rabit','Cow']
year_list = ['2008','2009','2010']
country_list = ['USA','GERMANY','ITALY']

with open('./products/animal_production.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as r:
     result = r.read()
result = json.loads(result)

for item in result[:]:
    if (not str(item["Year"]) in year_list) or (not item["Name"] in product_list) or (not item["Country"] in country_list):
        result.remove(item)
print(result)
```

I need to prepare the result in a max of 1 minute so what is your suggestion or the fastest way to filter JSON?

Comment: change all those lists to sets and that might give you some improvement I guess, also instead of removing the items, just add the items that match to a new list

Comment: how about [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Comment: @python_user I already try set It doesn't change that much

Comment: @MuratDemir did you try adding them to a new list instead of removing? `[item for item in result if str(item["Year"] in year_list) or (item["Name"] in product_list) or (item["Country"] in country_list)]`

Comment: @python_user I try but it is just another way to get the data

Comment: it is not, removing from a list in a loop is slower than just adding to a new list, if you have tried, what is the time difference between that and the one I suggested?

Comment: Wait it is faster I try your way thank you so much

Comment: Just write your answer I will accept @python_user

Comment: use `jq` instead of Python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing from a list in a loop is slower, each remove is `O(n)` and that is done `n` times so `O(n^2)`, appending to a new list is `O(1)` and doing this `n` times is  `O(n)` in a loop. So you can try this

```
[item for item in result if str(item["Year"] in year_list) or (item["Name"] in product_list) or (item["Country"] in country_list)]
```

Filter based on the condition you need and add only those that match.

Comment: It is literally 100 times faster than I did thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the json file using Pandas dataframes, and then filter on the required columns.

**Why ?** because Pandas is column-based and therefore it's super fast for working with columns, it's built upon Series which is a one-dimensional labeled array (basically the column).

So you need something like that: (Assuming column names in json file are consistent)

```
import pandas as pd

product_list = ['Horse','Rabit','Cow']
year_list = ['2008','2009','2010']
country_list = ['USA','GERMANY','ITALY']

df = pd.read_json('./products/animal_production.json')

# Change the condition if it's not the desired one
condition = (df["Year"].isin(year_list) | (df["Name"].isin(product_list) | (df["Country"].isin(country_list)

df = df[condition]
```

I can't reproduce it to estimate the time needed but I am sure it would be hundreds or even thousands of times faster!

Comment: @Murat I'd love if you could try it and tell me how much faster you got on 2.5 GB of data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it will be much faster, but you might `json.load` rather than `read`-ing then `json.loads`ing i.e. rather than

```
with open('./products/animal_production.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as r:
     result = r.read()
result = json.loads(result)
```

you might do

```
with open('./products/animal_production.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as r:
     result = json.load(r)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I try it before It just a -1 code line.