# How to remove all objects in a list from a for loop with python?

Tags: python

I feel like this should be a pretty simple process but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

Goal: Loop through a list of objects and if they match a condition remove it.

Issue: This works until it needs to remove all objects from the list. It will not remove the last item.

Example (clearly simplified by same results):

```
def some_function(val):
    return True
on_shift2 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
print("MY ON SHIFT2", on_shift2)
for idx, val in enumerate(on_shift2):
    print(f"Index: {idx} & Value: {val}")
    if len(on_shift2) == 1:
        del (on_shift2) # remove the whole list
    else:
        check_user = some_function(val) # function to check if user is in list and if so return true
        if check_user:
            on_shift2.remove(val)
            # Also tried the following
            # del on_shift[idx] # Same result
            # on_shift.pop(idx) # Same result
print("MY ON SHIFT2", on_shift2)
```

Results:

```
MY ON SHIFT2 ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
Index: 0 & Value: user1
Index: 1 & Value: user3
MY ON SHIFT2 ['user2']
```

Now the really odd part here is no matter what is in the list, it always seems to keem the middle item (i.e. user2). If i changed those values to chicken, horse, dog - the remaining item would be horse. Not sure if that's important but thought i would bring it up.

Also, no matter the which method i choose to remove the the items from the list (pop, remove or del), the 3rd (or last) item never gets removed if they all return true from "some_function()".

Also when looping through the if condition on the len(on_shift) never does equal 1, it always stops at 2. Never makes it to the 3rd (or last) object if the all return true from "some_fuction()", so my if statement to delete the list never happens.

If i print the val for the loop without removing anything from the list, all 3 names show up. I have to be doing something silly here.

Thoughts?

Comment: you should not remove from a list while iterating, if you must do so , then `for idx, val in enumerate(on_shift2.copy())` copy and then delete, your if condition `if len(on_shift2) == 1` is not needed anymore

Comment: I'm getting a different error: `NameError: name 'on_shift2' is not defined`

Comment: try without `if check_user:` line and see what happens. I guess the problem is in this line it returns false sometimes and all items do not get deleted.

Comment: @phython_user thank you for the quick reply. This is what i needed. If you want to set this as an answer ill mark it as correct. @David I get that error when i use .copy() and leave the code the same as the list gets removed in the `if len(on_shift2)` clause.

Comment: @Sudipto at times what you are saying is true and that part was working fine, i just couldn't figure out how to get it to remove all them when it was 100% true.

Comment: `filter` seems a better function to use here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify a list while iterating over it, but if you must do so, then you need to a make a copy of the list and iterate over the copy, but delete the elements from the original list.

```
def some_function(val):
    return True

on_shift2 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

print("MY ON SHIFT2", on_shift2)

for idx, val in enumerate(on_shift2.copy()):  # copy here
    print(f"Index: {idx} & Value: {val}")
    check_user = some_function(val) # function to check if user is in list and if so return true
    if check_user:
        on_shift2.remove(val)  # delete in original
print("MY ON SHIFT2", on_shift2)
```

Output

```
MY ON SHIFT2 ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
Index: 0 & Value: user1
Index: 1 & Value: user2
Index: 2 & Value: user3
MY ON SHIFT2 []
```

This is actually slower, a better alternative would be to [add only those you need to a different list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045049/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-filter-over-2-5gb-json-file/67045210#67045210).

```
on_shift2_new = [i for i in on_shift2 if not some_function(i)]
```

Comment: great alternative solution as well! I will test with both to see if performance is an issue and if so i will move the "false" items to a new list rather than do the copy.